# How can I handle bounce management in Communities programatically?

Tags: community, chatter, notification, bounce-management

#### The Problem

We have an active customer community with 25K+ users. These users are in many Chatter groups and as a result receive Chatter digests and notifications via email. About 300+ emails bounce back per week, from Chatter notifications sent to these users and we would like to automatically Freeze these users.

#### Possible Solutions

I know Salesforce has a bounce management feature for email deliverability but I believe it is only for contact or lead sent an email by workflow or apex. According to the docs, this doesn't cover community users.

I could also implement an email handler on my inbox that receives the bounces and implement some logic for freezing these users.

Is there a record created for these Chatter notification bounces that I could use to manage this in a batch job?

Any other possible solutions I'm not considering?

Comment: What if you send an email to all your community (i.e.: future release coming). But instead of sending email to the user object to the related contact. Then you will know which ones are not delivered and you could freeze them.

Comment: Chatter is really the communications nervous system of Communities, so my question is really aimed at how to handle bounces from Chatter notifications in communities.

Comment: greenstork I'm sorry no one could give you any answers - would love to hear the solution you ended up implementing as I am facing the same challenge myself.

Comment: No solution @smohyee ... we will have to wait for the platform to add this.